# Beacon transfer other beacon signal

Tags: ibeacon, beacon

I would like to create the indoor positioning system. I hope the system can collect all beacon signal and create map automatically. However, I know that far away beacon maybe cannot detect. Therefore, is that possible to discovery far away beacon based on other beacon? That is, beacon can transfer their signal based on other beacon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no, it is not possible to use a beacon to relay signals of more distant beacons.  Bluetooth beacons are extremely simple devices that just transmit a unique identifier.   They are transmit only, and therefore completely unaware of other beacons around them.

Comment: One more question. I hope the user can receive some push notification when they are near the IBeacon. The deisign of system should be: Phone receive beacon id and then ask the system corresponding message to phone. After that, phone display message. Like this?

Comment: Yes, a beacon can trigger a "local notification" on a phone if you have an app installed on that phone.  This is accomplished by simply writing code that sends the local notification in the beacon detection callback inside the app.